# Overlaying images in R Shiny

Tags: r, image, shiny

**EDIT:** solved with magick - thank you guys a lot :) Updated version in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/einGlasRotwein/R-eindeer), for anyone who's interested in the story of the reindeer.

I'm quite new to R and just got to know **R Shiny**. Yet, I am trying to do a reindeer generator. Basic principle: Combine different **layers of images** in order to create your personal reindeer. E.g. switch coat colours with buttons while the outlines still stay in place on top. Ideally, it should look something like this in the end (a preview I sketched with GIMP):

[preview of the reindeer generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1USQ.jpg)

I manage to get the images into Shiny and switch between two coats with radio buttons, for a start. 
However, I don't have a clue how to display the images at the same time at the very same location so the outlines will be an extra layer on top of the coat.

You can see the issue here:

[grey coat selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4p41.jpg)

[brown coat selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1ufv.jpg)

Here is my code. Since the file name is partly generated by the radio button input, I left the paths like that.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("R-eindeer"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("check1","coat colour", choices = c("grey","brown"))
      ),

    mainPanel(
      imageOutput("reindeer_coat"),
      imageOutput("reindeer_outline")
      )
    )
  )


server <- function(input,output){

  getImage <- reactive({
    list(src = paste0("./coat/reindeer_", input$check1, ".png"),
         width = 500,
         height = 500)
  })

  output$reindeer_coat <- renderImage({
    getImage()
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)

  output$reindeer_outline <- renderImage({
    return(list(src = "./outlines/reindeer_outline.png",
                width = 500,
                height = 500,
                contentType = 'image/png'))
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would appreciate any help. Even with that issue solved, there's still a long way to go - but maybe I can learn quick enough to get stuff done until Christmas ;-)

PS: You can find all the folders, image layers and additional information in the **Git repo** I just created. Also, even if you can't solve my question: feel free to use the images and pass on the Christmas spirit. Reindeer content should always be free. [Link to GitHub repo](https://github.com/einGlasRotwein/R-eindeer)

Comment: check out the `magick` package it is one of the main image manipulation packages. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html

Comment: PS Your project looks fun!  Let me know if the section on layers in that link does not give you what you need and I will be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you as well :) magick did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [`magick`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html) can do this for you! Specifically, `image_mosaic` will overlay images.

Try this out:

```
library(shiny)
library(magick)

ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("R-eindeer"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons("check1","coat colour", choices = c("grey","brown"))
        ),

        mainPanel(
            imageOutput("reindeer")
        )
    )
)


server <- function(input,output){

    get_image <- function(type, color) {
        image_read(file.path(type, paste0(color, ".png")))
    }

    output$reindeer <- renderImage({

        # load the images
        coat <- get_image("coat", paste0("reindeer_", input$check1))
        outline <- get_image("outlines", "reindeer_outline")

        # make the reindeer: overlay in order
        reindeer <- c(coat, outline)

        # create a temp file
        tmpfile <- reindeer %>%
            image_mosaic() %>%
            image_flatten() %>%
            image_write(tempfile(fileext='jpg'), format = 'jpg')

        # render the file
        return(list(src = tmpfile,
                    height = 300,
                    width = 300,
                    alt = "Your reindeer",
                    contentType = "image/jpg"))
    }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Oh my, that is really - magical! It did the trick and it makes me really happy to see this work. Thank you so much!

Comment: @einGlasRotwein I'm glad it helped! Good luck on your project -- I look forward to building my own reindeer!