# Draw shapes over image in R Shiny Magick

Tags: r, shiny

Ultimately I would like to display a number of small sprites over a background image, where the position of each sprite would be specified by specific coordinates. I looked into the magick package, but i was not able to find how to implement this specific functionality. The closest to what i need is to draw shapes over the image. This works fine in R:

```
library(magick)
image <- image_read("https://illustoon.com/photo/dl/7252.png")
image <- image_draw(image)
rect(313,354,341,382, col = "red")
```

, but not in Shiny:

```
library(magick)
#Modified from #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601495/overlaying-images-in-r-shiny
ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
      imageOutput("img")
    )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  image <- image_read("https://illustoon.com/photo/dl/7252.png")
  output$img <- renderImage({
      tmpfile <- image %>%
      image_draw() %>%
      rect(313,354,341,382, col = "red")%>%
      #image_mosaic()%>%
      #image_flatten()%>%
      image_write(tempfile(fileext='jpg'), format = 'jpg')
    list(src = tmpfile, contentType = "image/jpeg")
  }, deleteFile = TRUE)
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

where i get Error: cannot coerce type 'externalptr' to vector of type 'list'.
The problem is with the output of `rect`: not sure how to convert it back to png/jpeg. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining `rect` and the `magick` image will rather not work. It is more desirable to stick with `magick::` functionalities. A possibility is to create the rectangle with `image_blank` and combine it with the original image using `image_draw()`. Notice that you can define the position of the rectangle using the `offset` parameter.

```
tmpfile <- image %>%
            image_draw() %>%
            image_composite(image_blank(41, 41, "red"), offset = "+300+500") |> 
            image_write(tempfile(fileext='jpg'), format = 'jpg')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It should work until i figure out how to precisely overlay sprites/icons on the background.